# Как реализовать отталкивание шарика в массиве?

Tags: java, c#, c++

Есть двумерный массив `array[n][m]`. Из любого угла пускаем шарик, который будет двигаться под углом 45 градусов. Через сколько ходов шарик будет в другом углу?

Как реализовать отталкивание от стенок массива?

Comment: Что такое "угол", и то такое "другой угол"?

Comment: ...С минуту Алиса задумчиво смотрела на гриб, пытаясь определить, где у него одна сторона, а где - другая...

Answer (score 1):

Ну проверяем на граничные индексы, то есть примерно так:

```
if(row == 0 || column != 0) // верхняя стенка
{
   ++row;
   column = (двигался вправо)? column + 1 : column - 1; //надо знать, понятно, куда летел
}
```

Ну и так далее

Answer (score 1):

Если границы от которых должен быть отскок строго вертикальные и горизонтальные, то алгоритм и механика довольно простые, вообще говоря для произвольных углов.

Сразу введем две переменных, задающих вектор движения, для движения под углом 45 градусов значения смещений в целых координатах будут такими:

```
int dx = 1;// 1  -1  -1
int dy = 1;//-1   1  -1
```

Для произвольного угла, dx = cos(a), dy = sin(a).

Теперь цикл движения будет выглядеть предельно просто:

```
while(!stop)//подставьте условие завершения движения
{
    ball.X += dx;
    ball.Y += dy;
}
```

Ни каких проверок и прочих прелестей, и к тому же, работает для произвольных координат и смещений.

Теперь отражения. Главное при этом соблюсти законы физики, а именно: угол падения равен углу отражения для упругих соударений. Не ничего проще. Добавляем условие отражения в цикл.

```
while(!stop)//подставьте условие завершения движения
{
    if(ball.X+dx > m-1 || ball.X+dx < 0) 
        dx = -dx;
    if(ball.Y+dy > n-1 || ball.Y+dy < 0) 
        dx = -dx;
    ball.X += dx;
    ball.Y += dy;
}
```

Теперь шарик будет отражаться от встреченных стенок и углов до тех пор пока не будет выполнено условие выхода из цикла. При столкновении со стенкой соответствующий компонент вектора меняет знак, что обеспечивает сохранение угла при любых вещественных значениях компонент вектора движения. На этом все. Просто, прозрачно, не требует сложных вычислений.

---

Для случая с произвольными препятствиями и произвольным углом стенок все немного сложнее, но если имеете представление о переходе из одной системы координат в другую, то тоже не составляет большой сложности и не слишком сильно раздует алгоритм, хотя подумать над эффективной реализацией конечно придется основательно.

Answer (score 0):

Пусть текущая скорость шарика x, y - целые переменные, которые измеряются в клеточка/ход. Когда наш шарик у границы, к примеру (псевдокод): `if (ball.x >= width - 1) ball.velX = -ball.velX` - когда шарик оказывается в последней х-позиции - инвериируем его скорость по `х`. Аналогично для `y` и положения шарика в 0 координат.